# Relative 1 form of Frobenius morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, frobenius-map

Let $X$ be a connected smooth algebraic variety over a field $k$ of characteristic $p > 0$. We can consider the Frobenius morphism associated to $X \mapsto Spec(k)$. I'd like to show $\Omega^{1}_{X/X^{(p)}}$ is a locally free sheaves of dimension $dim(X)$.

The statement is of course local so we can assume $X = Spec(B)$ where $B$ is finitely generated $k$ algebra with only one generic point.

In the particular case where $B = k[x_{1}, ..., x_{n}]$, we have $X^{(p)} = Spec(k[x_{1}, ..., x_{n}] \otimes_{k} k)$ where the structure of $k$ algebra on $k$ is given by the  Frobenius. Note that $X \mapsto X^{(p)}$ is induced by the morphism $b \otimes_{k}a \in A:= k[x_{1}, ..., x_{n}] \otimes_{k} k \mapsto ab^{p} \in B := k[x_{1}, ..., x_{n}]$. Let us show $\Omega_{B/A}^{1}$ is free of rank $n$ on $A$. Let consider $\Omega$ the free $B-$module generated by the $dT_{1}, ..., dT_{n}$. We show $d : F \in B \mapsto \sum_{j} \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{j}}dT_{j} \in \Omega$ is an $A$ derivation (using the usual Leibniz rule, the fact that $pc = 0$ if $c \in k[x_{1}, ..., x_{n}]$ and the partial derivates of element in $k$ are $0$). Using the universal propertie, we show $\Omega \simeq \Omega^{1}_{B/A}$.

I think the Noether normalisation lemma could be usefull but I can't use it.

Comment: Because the pull-back map $F^*\Omega_{X^{(p)}/k}\to \Omega_{X/k}$ is zero, we have $\Omega_{X/X^{(p)}} \simeq \Omega_{X/k}$.

Comment: It works since the statement you told me about is true! (considering the local case).